# C# Check if Class is Null for Class with Custom == operator

Tags: c#, operators, nullreferenceexception

I'm creating a simple `class` that defines a number (real, imaginary, or complex).  To make things simple for myself when using the `class`, I'v created my own version of the `operator ==`.

```
public class Number
{
    public double Real { get; set; }
    public double Imag { get; set; }

    ...

    public static bool operator ==(Number x, Number y)
    {
        return (x.Real == y.Real && x.Imag == y.Imag);  // Error is thrown here
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Number x, Number y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
}
```

However, when I want to check if the `Number` is `null`, the code throws a NullReferenceException

```
Number overlap = null;
Number overlapsolve = null;

...

if (overlap != null && overlapsolve != null)  // This is what triggers the error
{
    ...
}
```

How can I check if the `Number` class is `null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, do you know of [`System.Numerics.Complex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? That seems to be exactly what you need.

But to answer your question, change your `==` operator to look like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(Number x, Number y)
{
     if(ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

     if(ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;

     return x.Real == y.Real && x.Imag == y.Imag;  
}
```

Be careful not to use `==` for the null checks as that would end up becoming an infinite recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Object.ReferenceEquals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see if it's null:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
{
    // x is null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's returning back an NullReferenceException because when you do the != check you are checking if

```
x.Real == y.Real
```

if either x or y is null, you will throw that exception.  You can do a simple check in the overloaded operator to check for this condition before you check for equality.